# Generation of MD5 is slow and missing first char

Tags: android

Currently I am trying to generate an MD5 of a large data file (10mb+). My current logic generates an MD5 but is cutting off the first character of the MD5. Also, the process is fairly slow, taking at least thirty seconds maybe more.

How do I not get it to cut off first char of MD5?

How can I speed the generation process up?

*UPDATED* Current code:

```
    File PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File DATAFILE = new File(PATH + "/stuff/content/" + FILE);

    Context context = MyApp.getAppContext();
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(DATAFILE);
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

   // generate MD5
    byte[] dataBytes = new byte[1024];
    int byteCount;
    while ((byteCount = in.read(dataBytes)) > 0) {
        md.update(dataBytes, 0, byteCount);
    }
    byte[] digest = md.digest();

    // convert to readable string
    String MD5;
    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i=0; i<digest.length; i++)
        hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & digest[i]));
    MD5 = hexString.toString();

    Log.i("GENERATED MD5", MD5);
```

Result:
02-19 15:44:59.528: I/GENERATED MD5(24222): cd8f8438957ea9db758ddd12d86e2ca

Should be:
"md5":"0cd8f8438957ea9db758ddd12d86e2ca"

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You (were) calling BuffererdInputStream.read() and MessageDigest.update() once for each byte in the input data.

Instead use a byte array as a buffer and call the array forms of these functions, it'll probably be faster.

**Edit:**

The reason your strings don't match is because the top bits of the first byte are 0, so `Integer.toHexString()` is returning "c" when you expect "0c".

You can fix this by using String.format to pad the hex digits with zeros.

Change your code from:

```
hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & digest[i]));
```

To this (the `0xFF &` isn't needed since you're working with bytes already):

```
hexString.append(String.format("%02x", digest[i]));
```

Comment: But would this be causing me to be missing the first char?

Comment: Still having issue of missing first char...posted my latest logic.

Answer (score -1):

This is what solved my issue. It seems there was a flaw in my previous logic that only will occur when the first character was zero. Interesting why more examples don't include what I have below.

```
    // convert to readable string
    String MD5;
    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i = 0; i < digest.length; i++) {
        String hex = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & digest[i]);
        if (hex.length() == 1) {
            hexString.append('0');
        }
        hexString.append(hex);
    }

    MD5 = hexString.toString();

    Log.i("GENERATED MD5", MD5);
```

Comment: Yuck!  Sorry, that's a really hacky way of solving the problem - look at my edit for a better way of doing it.